# In golang, what is the fastest way to remove stop words?

Tags: go, stop-words

I've created a go [package to remove stopwords](https://github.com/bbalet/stopwords) and I'm trying to optimize it.

Based on my research, the average list of stop words in many languages contains around 300 words.

In the current version of the package, I'm using a simple map in order to store the list of stop words. Then, I break words in the original content and recreate a filtered content by adding the words that are not in the map (of stopwords).

I've tried to use a [bloom filter](https://github.com/willf/bloom), but it doesn't improve the performance. I think it's due to two factors :

- Bloom filters are fast when it comes to search into a large set, but they cost a lot to build (even if it is built once). So the overall gain is little where m is about 300.
- In the current version, I used maps and, if I remeber well, go builds a hashmap for searching the key faster.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: What's your bottleneck when you profile your program?

Comment: The line that tests if it is a stop words... either if _, ok := dict[w]; ok { or if filter.Test([]byte(w)) {

Comment: you should use a map[string]struct{} - using a map of empty struct is less memory hungry than using a map of strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try building a regex by pasting together all of your candidate words with `|` and compiling it ahead of time. The RE2 regex engine will convert the big list of alternations into an efficient trie data structure for matching. You can do it like:

```
reStr := ""

for i, word := range words {
    if i != 0 {
        reStr += `|`
    }
    reStr += `\Q` + word + `\E`
}
re := regexp.MustCompile(reStr)
```

(the `\Q` and `\E` prevent any problems in the unlikely case that any of the words in the list contain regex metacharacters, and are harmless otherwise).

Comment: Thank you. The exact expression should be something like var filter = regexp.MustCompile(`\A(a|along|another|yet)\z`) although you wanted to do something else than a match ? With a match this improve the speed by a factor of 60%.

Comment: @BenjaminBALET I would suggest not using the word splitter and trying to match individual words -- instead, match the stopword regex against the whole input string. That way the regex engine can efficiently skip over large numbers of non-matching words. If `ReplaceAllFunc` isn't powerful enough, then `FindStringIndex` should help you do the job.